# Why does this nested for-loop iterate twice over the second loop, and not at all afterwards?

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to process some data by running it through the functions defined below. It seems to run through the program just fine, but the loop doesn't iterate the number of times I expect it to.

It doesn't seem to matter where I put the return statement, so long as it's inside the function and not under the if statement.

I have tried writing lines under each for loop independently, and it writes the expected number of lines in each case.

```py
def _ManhattanDistance(x,y):
    a = 0
    for i in range(0,len(x)):
        a += abs(float(x[i])-float(y[i]))
    return a

def _CabFare(x,y,z):
    with open(x, 'r') as f:
        with open(y, 'r') as g:
            with open(z, 'wb') as h:
                reader_1 = csv.reader(f)
                reader_2 = csv.reader(g)
                writer = csv.writer(h)
                for row_b in reader_2:
                    for row_a in reader_1:
                        if _ManhattanDistance(row_a,row_b) > 0:
                            writer.writerow(row_a)
                            writer.writerow(row_b)
                return
```

For reference, given my inputs reader_1 should have 200 lines, and reader_2 should have 17145 lines. With our threshold for inclusion being zero, I expect 17145*200 = 3429000 lines in the output file- what I get is an output with 400 lines.

Comment: We'd need to see some sample data to see what's going on, I think. FWIW, I don't think you need a `return` statement at all here.

Comment: The elements of the dataset are fairly long vectors, I have a feeling that including some of them might just end up being more confusing than doing without. You're right about the second return statement- it's now discarded. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```py
from itertools import product

def _CabFare(x,y,z):
    with open(x, 'r') as f, open(y, 'r') as g, open(z, 'wb') as h:
        writer = csv.writer(h)
        for row_a, row_b in product(csv.reader(f), csv.reader(g)):
            if _ManhattanDistance(row_a, row_b) > 0:
                writer.writerow(row_a)
                writer.writerow(row_b)
```

Slower, but less memory intensive:

```py
def _CabFare(x,y,z):
    with open(x, 'r') as f, open(z, 'wb') as h:
        writer = csv.writer(h)
        for row_a in csv.reader(f):
            with open(y, 'r') as g:
                for row_b in csv.reader(g):
                    if _ManhattanDistance(row_a, row_b) > 0:
                        writer.writerow(row_a)
                        writer.writerow(row_b)
```

Comment: Might chew some memory, though.

Comment: Would you mind explaining why there is a difference between the two versions? As far as I understand the `with` container and the `csv.reader` rows generator, only one line is loaded at a time, so both versions seems quite equivalent and efficient to me.

Comment: The 1st uses `itertools.product()` and will read both input files only once - holding at least one of them in memory.

The 2nd re-reads the 2nd CSV for each row in the first. Lots of duplicate reading going on, but it only holds 2 rows in memory at a time, so low memory usage.

Comment: Thanks. This code seems a little closer- twice the amount of lines in the output than I was expecting though. I'll try to figure out why that is, but this seems close enough to what I'm looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: We are writing *two* rows for each combination of rows in the two input files - might that be it?

Comment: Yes, it absolutely was.

Answer (score 1):

`reader` is a stateful iterator. Once you exhaust it, it's done, and you need to reopen it in order to iterate over the file again:

```
def _CabFare(x,y,z):
    with open(x, 'r') as f:
        with open(y, 'r') as g:
            with open(z, 'wb') as h:
                reader_2 = csv.reader(g)
                writer = csv.writer(h)
                for row_b in reader_2:
                    reader_1 = csv.reader(f) # Reopen reader_1 for each iteration
                    for row_a in reader_1:
                        if _ManhattanDistance(row_a,row_b) > 0:
                            writer.writerow(row_a)
                            writer.writerow(row_b)
```

Comment: @DirtyBit they definitely could be, but that was immaterial to the OP's question, so I didn't want to touch it.

Comment: I tried implementing this code instead, and I'm still only getting 400 lines back.